# Building a background activity (Android)

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity behaving as my loadscreen, I want it to build a new activity, and call a method setControls() before setting it. This is important because it will allow me to give a progress bar for completion while databases are constructed for the first time.

But how do I start an object of a class extending AppCompatActivity, allowing me to interact with it, and then pass it to be the current activity?

```
public void setData() {
    this.activity = new HomeScreen();
//        I know this is how I would start an activity normally,
//        but I can't reach the methods like this...
//        Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, HomeScreen.class);
//        startActivity(activityIntent);
    loader = new GameLoader(this);
    gameExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    gameExecutor.submit(() -> {
        List<Future> gameSetup = activity.setControls();
        float tasks = gameSetup.size();
        int index = 0;
        float done = 0;
        while (!gameSetup.isEmpty()) {
            if (gameSetup.get(index).isDone()) {
                gameSetup.remove(index);
                --index;
                loader.drawOProgress(++done / tasks);
            }
            ++index;
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating an Async task that shows a progress bar on pre-execute and hides the progress bar on post-execute. In your do in background you load the databases.

The async task is then called in your activity